# Exit from React Native App to Flutter App on IOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, react-native

Hi developers and professionals,

I am integrating Flutter framework with React Native framework and everything works fine but I am having a problem when exiting React Native App to Flutter App (on iOS). I want it to be something like callback to Flutter app instead of exiting the whole app at once. On Android it's working fine. I don't have any problem with Android side. I wanted it to be callback to the Flutter App. Thank you in advance!

This is the React Native on pressed code:

`try {  Platform.OS === "ios" ? RNExitApp.exitApp() : BackHandler.exitApp(); }`

These are the simulations:

[image]

From Flutter App to React Native App

[image]

Exiting to Flutter App from React Native App

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution for this? We're hitting a similar challenge. But instead of going back to flutter, it goes back to native IOS. But I think the methodology should be similar.